# Microsoft Word 2010 page number to be 2 digits

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

At the moment I cannot format the page number to be 2 digits in `Microsoft Word 2010`.

If you know how to, please share. Thank you!

Below is my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Right click** the page number and select **Toggle Field Codes**.

[image: field codes]

Field codes of

```
{PAGE \# "00"}
```

```
{NUMPAGES \# "00"}
```

will give you page numbers with two digits. Now, press <kbd>F9</kbd> or select **Update Field** to display the result.

---

More information: [Insert and format field codes in Word 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2010-HA101830917.aspx)